# Wildcard SSL Certificates, Custom Domain Names, and Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, https, wildcard, cloudflare

I have a domain with a wildcard SSL certificate (https://domainA.com). I have users who use custom subdomains (https://user1.domainA.com). I have users who wish to use custom domains that point to their subdomains (CNAME records from https://domainB.com to https://user1.domainA.com).

The problem with these custom domains is that they throw an SSL warning in the browser, as the domain name on the SSL certificate (https://*.domainA.com) does not match the domain name being used to access the page (https://domainB.com).

Enter Cloudflare.

By using Cloudflare's Full SSL service, on https://domainB.com, I can suppress the SSL warning so users experience no problems. I know that the SSL warning exists (as disabling Cloudflare will cause the warning to re-appear), but Cloudflare silently dismisses the warning and proceeds with the encryption.

Also, by using Full SSL, I am theoretically encrypting traffic completely between the user and the server.

My question has to do with the security/legitimacy of this solution, to apply SSL encryption any domains (https://domainB.com, https://domainC.com) that users may wish to use to reach their pages (https://user1.domainA.com).

Is this secure?  Is this safe?  Is this responsible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few factors to this.

One is how far you trust CloudFlare. They will see your users' traffic in plaintext, after decrypting the tunnel between them and the user and before re-encrypting it to the origin server.

Secondly, CloudFlare are not doing *any* validation of the server's certificate with the Full SSL (non-strict) option. This means that it's not just about domain matching: none of the cert attributes: issuer, time range et al are checked.
Hence, someone can do a Man-in-the-middle attack between CloudFlare and you.

So, I wouldn't say it's very safe or secure, but it really depends on the type of data passing on your HTTPs channel.

It might be worth considering HTTP 301 redirect from https://domainB.com to https://userX.domainA.com rather than going for CNAME records, and using CloudFlare's Full (strict) SSL, if you're strongly concerned about your users' data.