# How should an HTTP be listed under Google's API when using Cloudflare's shared SSL?

Tags: ssl, https, google-api, cloudflare, google-oauth

From my research I'm not getting an answer after referencing:

- [Custom SSL doesn't show when using CloudFlare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532582/custom-ssl-doesnt-show-when-using-cloudflare)
- [How to append SSL Origin Certificate with CloudFlare's Root Certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205161/how-to-append-ssl-origin-certificate-with-cloudflares-root-certificate)
- [Assets not loaded when using CloudFlare SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565023/assets-not-loaded-when-using-cloudflare-ssl)
- [Cloudflare SSL issue: Request origin does not match request base_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895855/cloudflare-ssl-issue-request-origin-does-not-match-request-base-url)
- [CloudFlare SSL refused on HTTP access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219932/cloudflare-ssl-refused-on-http-access)
- [Wildcard SSL Certificates, Custom Domain Names, and Cloudflare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880872/wildcard-ssl-certificates-custom-domain-names-and-cloudflare)

In my domain register I point my domain nameservers to Cloudflare and under Cloudflare's Crypto set SSL to **Full**. When I add the URL under Client ID for web application -> Restrictions -> **Authorized JavaScript origins** and **Authorized redirect URIs** should I be using HTTP, HTTPS, or both?

My understanding Cloudflare's SSL is a shared SSL and not a dedicated SSL. From Google's documentation I am unaware or able to find when using the Google Login API if the API will work successfully using a shared SSL.

The app is a web application written in Node using Google's Login API and hosted with a custom domain on Heroku. I am able to get the application to work locally and with Heroku's generated URL but I'd like to also implement Cloudflare I'm just unsure what is the correct way to use a shared SSL.

So to sum up, if I own the domain `foobar.com` in Google's *Restrictions* should I be using:

```
http://foobar.com
http://www.foobar.com
```

or

```
https://foobar.com
https://www.foobar.com
```

if the SSL is a shared SSL from Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how do you want to expose your domain to users. Both protocols http/https can be allowed.

However you are trying to use "`Google's Login API`" = probably `Open ID Connect` client (`SAML` client is different), which needs encryption -> so actually, you need to allow only https protocol and then you will have safe configuration.